# Query string to pre-fill HTML form with uncertain IDs

Tags: html, url, query-string

I am trying to create an URL to a pre-filled form.

As of current, I have the URL

```
http://www.example.com/new?user=12345&subject=hello&message=example
```

However, due to changes on the target website, this link no longer works.
The IDs of the fields are always changing, instead of `id="subject"` it says `id="subject_id923847-34567-4045-ba78-00hj90467ba0347"`

Is there a workaround for this?
For example, the closest match, or the nth field number.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the ID in the URL example you showed us? Please show a relevant example with relevant expected output and how you plan to fill the target form

Comment: I expect `http://www.example.com/new?subject=Hello` to result in the form's subject field being pre-filled with "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

So something like

```
const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
document.querySelector("[id^=subject]").value  = params.get('subject');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
What I need to do is to create an URL -- not a code. I want to be able to, through an URL, access the field with `id="subject_x"`.
This could be done with `http://www.example.com/new?subject_x=Hello`, but the issue is that the `x` is always a different value. Before going to the link I do not know what `x` is. In other words, I am looking for a wildcard or a nth functions. Everything through an URL query string. Does this make sense?